# Why do we use ctrl + c / ctrl + x / ctrl + z in terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Why do we have to use all this shortcut to quit the programs in `terminal` ?

For example :

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in order to quit `top`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in order to quit `man`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> in order to quit `nano`

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> isn't suppose to kill the program ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it's specified in POSIX, the IEEE norm for Unix-like computer systems.

Check [Section 10.2 - Output Devices and Terminal Types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) of the POSIX.1 2008 (the latest) specification for all the shortcuts available.

To add up to your question, this is a brief explanation of what those shortcuts actually do.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-[letter], you are actually sending a signal to the process. A signal is a "flag" you provide to the process that gets interpretated and associated with an action.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sends SIGINT, a signal that causes the process to terminate.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> sends SIGTSTP, a signal this causes the process to suspend execution. In this case, it is resumable - try executing a command that will take a while and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>; you'll see something in the lines of

  `[1]+ Stopped [your command]`.

  Type `fg` in your Terminal and you'll see the process resuming, if it didn't end before resuming it.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, in this case, is the shortcut nano uses to exit the process. Incidentally, there is a signal associated to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, but it's not related to nano.

TL;DR It's specified in POSIX.

Comment: `fg` for "foreground" if it helps you remember it. Also `jobs` to list

Comment: Would be very usefull to also add "bg" (background) for resuming a process in the background, i.e., keeping the terminal available for other commands

Comment: Why doesn't `man` handle `ctrl-c`?

Answer (score 3):

`+z` and `+c` are shell signals.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is not killing the program, it is sending it a signal (`SIGTSTP`) to **suspend**. Type `fg` to resume it. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is another signal, this time the `SIGINT` to **terminate**. <kbd>kbd+x</kbd> is just a nano key binding.